# My computer gets hosted when using 3G

Tags: linux, networking, 3g

I recently activated 3G(UMTS) connection on my cellular network. I use Nokia S60 phone as a modem while connecting from Scientific Linux 6.

While I am able to access net pretty well, the problem is my computer gets hosted. By using ip-address in a web-browser, anyone can access my localhost (running apache), this never happens with my wireline (ADSL) connection. Furthermore, even the Shell prompt changes from:

```
[mach2@localhost ~]$
```

to

```
[mach2@XX.XX.XX.XX ~]$
```

where XX.XX.XX.XX is the IP of the 3G connection. The very thought of putting my machine 'in the wild' is disconcerting. How can I rectify the situation without disabling services like apache, sshd and others?

Comment: please tell us first two groups of digits of the IP address

Comment: @serge As requested: 42.105.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the GSM operator assigned you the public IP you should ensure that you enabled the firewall  on your connection. In linux the firewall is based on netfilter(iptables). Most distributions have GUI to set it up. However, if you miss it you can set the minimal set of rules manually:

```
$ iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$ iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
$ iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

or put the rules into `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

then make sure the iptables init script is started at boot:

```
$ chkconfig iptables on
```

and start it:

```
$ service iptables start
```

Comment: [Top 5 Best Linux Firewalls](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/top-5-best-linux-firewalls/)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this without any details about configuration.
But when using ADSL you'll be most likely connected to a router which has a firewall(iptables) running which disallows any connections from outside.
That's why one explicitly has to forward ports when one wants e.g. sshd to be visible from outside.

Using 3G it depends on the configuration of your mobile provider. Some forbid connections from outside but most don't. So you'll have to set up your iptables firewall properly to reject any incoming packets from your 3G device that are not belonging to established connections.

Your prompt (assuming you use bash) is set by the environment variable `$PS1`, usually the hostname is displayed.
It can be set by in `/etc/sysconfig/network`. Depending on your configuration is possible that your hostname gets changed by DHCP when you connect to your provider.
Try setting your desired hostname using `dhcp_hostname=your.hostname.here` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (change eth0 with your network device)